# Can MongoDB project operator convert into object instead of array?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

If I good understand MongoDB project returns an array. What if I would have an object at the end of a `find` operation. The keys would be the `_id` and the values, the selected field. Is it any operation for it?

It Swift / Vapor language the `flatten` with this operation `Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues:` is used for it.

```
db.bios.find( { }, {_id: _id, name: 1, contribs: 1 } )
```

Comment: You can use `$arrayToObject` inside an aggregation pipeline to get such a result, but it will still be one object inside an array. It may also suffer from the size limit of a document.

Comment: Maybe I should use `Object.fromEntries()` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries

Comment: mongodb can't return this format of array of [key, value]